# Insert data does not exist in database but response is TRUE

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

```
$DataInsert = [
                'id' => $Id,
                'name' => $name,
                'price' => $Price,
                'available' => $Stock,
            ];

            $this->db->table('services')->insert($DataInsert)  //This data does not enter the database but the response is TRUE
```

I know there is a column with a data type that doesn't match the data I entered, but why is the response `true` although this is not entered into the database?

Comment: how are you checking the return value (true/false) of `insert()` method ?

Comment: I use

if($this->db->table('services')->insert($DataInsert) == true) {
//MESSAGE
}

and I try to use the dd() function like this dd($this->db->table('services')->insert($DataInsert));

The data is not entered in the database but the result returned is true.

Comment: dd() is not a native PHP Function so you should use either var_dump() or print_r(). I have had a dig through the through code itself and you might be better using !== false which reads as " (!=) Not Equal to Value and (!==) Type". So it must be "Not False" and It Must be a Boolean. You should read up on the differences between what can evaluate to True and False in PHP.

Comment: do you have model for services table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$DataInsert = array(
            'id' => $Id,
            'name' => $name,
            'price' => $Price,
            'available' => $Stock,
        );
$this->db->table('services')->insert($DataInsert);
if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
   //message
}
```

If you insist on evaluating the insert() method use this instead.

```
if($this->db->table('services')->insert($DataInsert) !==FALSE){
  //message
}
```